# Why is SQL Plus prompting me to enter value?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a `query.sql` file that looks like this:

```
define start_date = '2020-02-01 00:00:00'
define end_date = '2020-02-20 00:00:00'

select * from customers where created_time between '&start_date' and '&end_date';
```

When I execute it in SQL Plus, I got a prompt to enter a value for `start_date` and `end_date`:

```
SQL> @query
Enter value for start_date: 
Enter value for end_date:
```

Why? I thought I defined them in the script?

---

**Edit:** the `created_time` is of type TIMESTAMP. I tried changing the query to:

```
define start_date = timestamp'2020-02-01 00:00:00'
define end_date = timestamp'2020-02-20 00:00:00'

select * from customers where created_time between &start_date and &end_date;
```

But was hit with a different error:

```
SQL> @query
old   1: select * from customers where created_time between &start_date and &end_date
new   1: select * from customers where created_time between timestamp'2020-02-01 and timestamp'2020-02-20
select * from customers where created_time between timestamp'2020-02-01 and timestamp'2020-02-20
                                                                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23
```

Comment: Is that the entire script? It has some issues but it shouldn't be prompting you, unless something else is happening between the define and the use of the variables.

Comment: @AlexPoole it's the simplified version of the script. In the actual script, it does not matter if I move the `define` to right above the `select`, still got the same error. And it only happens when I execute the external file

Comment: And you're sure it's coming from *that* script, not another one it calls earlier (before the define) - which I guess you can verify by adding some PROMPT calls as debug to check the position; and it's running from your current directory - it isn't picking up a different file with the  same name from your SQLPATH, say?

Comment: Regarding your TIMESTAMP literal use: the new error you are getting is due to the fact that the TIMESTAMP literal **must** include the time component. You could add ` 00:00:00` at the end, if that is what you need, but you cannot omit it altogether.

Comment: The define *does* have the time, it's just being lost in translation. If that was missing it would be a different error.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, fix the formats of the literals :

```
SQL> define start_date = date'2020-02-01'
SQL> define end_date = date'2020-02-20'
```

and then get rid of redundant quotes which are already put during the initialization

```
SQL> select * from customers where created_time between &start_date and &end_date;
```

*I suppose `created_time` is of date type, isn't it?*

If the data type is timestamp as mentioned in the comment, then replace the `date` keywords with `timestamp` for the variable definitions

```
SQL> define start_date = timestamp'2020-02-01 00:00:00'
SQL> define end_date = timestamp'2020-02-20 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `created_time` is actually TIMESTAMP. Your answer works if I type it in the SQL Plus prompt, but give me a different error when running from the external file

Comment: you're welcome @MikeHenderson , in that case you can replace the literals such as `timestamp'2020-02-01'`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second issue with timestamps; you're doing

```
define start_date = timestamp'2020-02-01 00:00:00'
define end_date = timestamp'2020-02-20 00:00:00'

select * from customers where created_time between &start_date and &end_date;
```

but notice how that appears once substituted:

```
old   1: select * from customers where created_time between &start_date and &end_date
new   1: select * from customers where created_time between timestamp'2020-02-01 and timestamp'2020-02-20
```

Because the value you are setting has a space in it, you need to enclose that in double quotes:

```
define start_date = "timestamp '2020-02-01 00:00:00'"
define end_date = "timestamp '2020-02-20 00:00:00'"

select * from customers where created_time between &start_date and &end_date;
```

which is now substituted as:

```
old   1: select * from customers where created_time between &start_date and &end_date
new   1: select * from customers where created_time between timestamp '2020-02-01 00:00:00' and timestamp '2020-02-20 00:00:00'
```

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/DEFINE.html) actually says to enclose in single quotes, but since your value has those you would need to escape them:

```
define start_date = 'timestamp ''2020-02-01 00:00:00'''
define end_date = 'timestamp ''2020-02-20 00:00:00'''
```

which also works, but in this instance double quotes are a bit easier.

---

By the way, `between` is inclusive, so your query (when it works) will pick up any rows with exactly 2020-02-20 00:00:00, which I imagine is not your intent. You can do:

```
select * from customers
where created_time >= &start_date
and created_time < &end_date;
```

If you intended to have all rows from 2020-02-20 you would need to increase the end-date by a day to pick those up.

---

None of which explains your initial problem of being prompted for the variables though... if that still happens once the timestamp situation is resolved, then it's coming from later in the script - or from another script this one, calls perhaps.